# How to modify the login page to reflect what happened to the authentication?

Tags: php, javascript, html

There are two cases here.

1. The user enters an empty input. In this case, the login page will warn the user that he has entered an empty input.
2. The user enters the wrong username or password. In this case, the login page will warn the user that he has entered a wrong username or password.

In both the scenarios, the input processing will be done on the server(PHP). My problem is, how do I modify the login page dynamically to show the warning messages?

I tried passing the PHP boolean value into a javascript variable in login page but after some research, I found out that you cannot mix Javascript and PHP codes. The code is below:

```
function error_msg()
{
<?php session_start();?>
var failed_login= <?php echo $_SESSION['failed_login'];?>; 
var empty_field= <?php echo $_SESSION['empty_field'];?>; 
var txt=document.getElementById("failed_login_text");

if (empty_field== 1)
{
    txt.innerHTML="No empty fields allowed.";
    <?php unset($_SESSION['empty_field']);?>
}
else if (failed_login== 1)
{
        txt.innerHTML="Failed login. Wrong username or password.";
        <?php unset($_SESSION['failed_login']);?>
}

      <?php session_destroy();?>
}
```

Another method I used is by echoing the whole Javascript into the login.php using PHP. This PHP code is in the login page file.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $failed_login= $_SESSION['failed_login'];
    $empty_field= $_SESSION['empty_field'];

    echo $_SESSION["empty_field"];
    echo $_SESSION["failed_login"];

$script="<script>
var empty_field= $empty_field;
var failed_login= $failed_login;
var txt=document.getElementById(\"failed_login_text\");
txt.innerHTML= empty_field;

if (empty_field== 1)
{
    txt.innerHTML=\"No empty fields allowed.\";

}
else if (failed_login== 1)
{
        txt.innerHTML=\"Failed login. Wrong username or password.\";

}</script>";
echo $script;
unset($_SESSION['empty_field']);
unset($_SESSION['failed_login']);
?>
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I have written this  script for dynamic login , you can use it if it serves you , and i have used jquery for validation ,  Hope this might help you

```
<?php 
    if (isset($_POST['user'])){
     $email = $_POST['user'];
     $password = $_POST['password'];
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM `register` WHERE `email` = '{$email}' AND BINARY `password` = '{$password}'";
     $result  = mysql_query($sql);
     if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0)
     {
     $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
     $_SESSION['email'] = $row['email'];
     $_SESSION['sno'] = $row['sno'];
      header("location:some_page.php");
     }
     else
      {
        $msg ="Invalid Username / Password"; 
          header('location:your_page_name?msg='.$msg);  
      }
     }
     else
     {
        $msg = "Internal Server error";
     }
    ?>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>login-user</title>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="js/validity.form.js"></script>
    <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/jquery.validity.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/jquery-ui.css">

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
          $("#form1").validity(function() {
            $("#user").require().match("email");;
            $("#password").require();
                });
            });
    </script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <div id="container">
    <?php
        if(isset($_REQUEST['msg']) && $_REQUEST['msg']!='')
        {
            echo "<div id='message'>".$_REQUEST['msg']."</div>";
        }
    ?>
          <form id="form1" name="form1" method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
                <lable>User Name:</lable>
                  <input name="user" type="text" id="user" size="30" />
                <lable>Password:</lable>
                  <input name="password" type="password" id="password" size="30" value=""/>
                <input type="submit" name="Log In" id="Log In" value="Login" />
          </form>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```